# Can callback channels be spoofed?

Tags: wcf, spoofing

When users first connect to my sessionful service, they provide a user name in the form of a string. If multiple users have provided the same user name, the server appends all new users with a number that increments based on how many exist on the service already.

These user names are the value in a `Dictionary<IChatCallback, string>` dictionary. Whenever a user calls a method such as `SendMessage` on the server, the server detects who the caller is by doing a dictionary lookup based on  `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatCallback>()` as the key.

My question is... can this channel be spoofed? Can somebody somehow call methods on the service under someone elses callback channel, and the server is oblivious?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying WCF Client ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277256/identifying-wcf-client-id)